# Is it possible to save files outside of the sandbox via the built-in apps?

Tags: ios

If I have a `UIWebView` which has links to files then is it possible to save those files to disk outside of the application sandbox?

Yes I know an app can't access the filesystem outside of its sandbox, but could the saving process be done by whatever app can handle the file type? - For example if its an audio file, could my app launch QuickTime passing it the file (or file url) and the user is then able to save the file via the QuickTime app saving it in the appropriate location for audio files?

Comment: QuickTime isn't an app on iOS. What exactly are you trying to do? You might want to look into the Assets Library framework.

Comment: That was just an example, I'm loading pages in a UIWebView which may contain links to files such as audio, video, photos, maybe even pdf, calendar, etc. And there is a requirement to save them to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps are limited to saving data within their own sandbox. Which you seem to acknowledge already.

You can make one app launch another, which in theory could allow a second app to save data, but within its own sandbox. You also mention this.

In effect, you've answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write images to the photo album which is outside the sandbox.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture_of_my_cat.png"];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

In order to get data out from a UIWebView (javascript to objective C) you can subclass `NSURLProtocol` and use `jQuery.ajax`.