# iOS equivalent of Android external/public storage

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any equivalent of Android's external/public storage concept in IOS
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

I don't want the physical external storage in iOS but at least a common public folder where multiple apps can read/write from.

Also i want to check if there is any way to share a file between two applications on a same device. My file can get huge
AFAIK with air drop i can share files between applications in different devices.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to save files outside of the sandbox via the built-in apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605869/is-it-possible-to-save-files-outside-of-the-sandbox-via-the-built-in-apps)

Comment: You can share some kind of documents like PDF, text files etc between apps by using shareKit but I dont know what do you want to share actually?

Comment: thanks guyz for your responses...basically i want to share some information between two apps..so i was thinking of app a writing to a file and then app b reading from that file for informaton exchange...it can be a plain json/text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App groups can be a possible solution for your case if you are going to share data among your apps.

Otherwise creating an extension & allow user to store data in cloud storage could be a possible solution.
https://www.centerdevice.de/document-and-share-extensions-in-ios/

Comment: thanks Ellen...app groups was the solution i was looking for